# Wrap body.getAsync() inside a sync function

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

So I was following a [tutorial to build an Outlook Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/quick-start?tabs=visual-studio). However, the demo does not display the `body` of the message.

I also learned from the doc that I can call the `getAsync` to access to the body but it does not work. Do I need to use `async await` here?

Here is the code:

```
function loadProps() {
  $("#attachments").html(buildAttachmentsString(item.attachments));
  $("#cc").html(buildEmailAddressesString(item.cc));
  $("#conversationId").text(item.conversationId);
  $("#from").html(buildEmailAddressString(item.from));
  $("#internetMessageId").text(item.internetMessageId);
  $("#normalizedSubject").text(item.normalizedSubject);
  $("#sender").html(buildEmailAddressString(item.sender));
  $("#subject").text(item.subject);
  $("#to").html(buildEmailAddressesString(item.to));
  $("#body").text(buildEmailBodyString()); //async function
}

function buildEmailBodyString() {
  Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text, function callback(resText) {
    return resText.value;
  });
}
```

Comment: The `getAsync` probably comes from bluebird. The npm you are using is probably wrapped up in it.
http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html

Comment: @MaxBaldwin Doesn't look like it, a bluebird-promisified function would not take a callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that your `buildEmailBodyString` fires off `getAsync` and exists immediately. It isn't returning `restText.value` from the function because the function already existed.

```
function buildEmailBodyString() {
  // 1. Fires function
  Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text, function callback(resText) {
    // 3. returns a value to nothing
    return resText.value;
  });
  // 2. Exits function
}
```

One solution here would be to set `$("#body")` from within the callback:

```
function buildEmailBodyString() {
  Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text, function callback(resText) {
    $("#body").text(resText.value);
  });
}
```

You could also drop `buildEmailBodyString` entirely and call it within `loadProps` directory. This would simplify the code so it's a bit easier grok down the road:

```
function loadProps() {
  $("#attachments").html(buildAttachmentsString(item.attachments));
  $("#cc").html(buildEmailAddressesString(item.cc));
  $("#conversationId").text(item.conversationId);
  $("#from").html(buildEmailAddressString(item.from));
  $("#internetMessageId").text(item.internetMessageId);
  $("#normalizedSubject").text(item.normalizedSubject);
  $("#sender").html(buildEmailAddressString(item.sender));
  $("#subject").text(item.subject);
  $("#to").html(buildEmailAddressesString(item.to));

  // Retrieve Email Body
  Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text, function callback(resText) {
    $("#body").text(resText.value);
  });
}
```